# MDD validation bug with >=

Tags: makumba

I use this validation rule in the MDD:

```
compare(maxSizeOfGroup, minSizeOfGroup) {maxSizeOfGroup >= minSizeOfGroup} :
"The maximum number of people can't be smaller than the minimum number!"
```

Yet I see the error message I defined when I choose both to be the same number.

Btw, in the [documentation](http://www.makumba.org/page/ValidationRules) it says to use ">=" but that gives the error
 "[...] unexpected char: '\' [...]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed there is a bug with the "<=" and ">=" when having a live validation.

This will be fixed in the next release. Until then you will have to either disable the live validation, or just use different validation rules.

As for documentation, it has an escaping error. The "\" is not supposed to be there.